# Permission denied for SO files

Tags: android, java-native-interface, .so

Unable to initialise *.so files located in my libs folder. There is Permission Denied error showing in logcat.

Error:

```
E/art     (17495): dlopen("/data/data/XXXXX/files/libs/XXXX.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: couldn't map "/data/data/XXXXX/files/libs/XXXX.so" segment 2: Permission denied
E/NativeLoader(17495): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: couldn't map "/data/data/XXXX/files/libs/XXXX.so" segment 2: Permission denied
E/NativeLoader(17495):  at XXXX$1.run(XXXXX.java:65)
E/XX    (17495): Thread-794|E|AP|[XXXXX][uncaughtException] Uncaught UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int XXXX.engine.JNIEngine.initClass(java.lang.Object, int) (tried XXXXX_JNIEngine_initClass and XXXX_JNIEngine_initClass__Ljava_lang_Object_2I).|java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int XXXXX.JNIEngine.initClass(java.lang.Object, int) (tried XXXX_JNIEngine_initClass and XXXX_JNIEngine_initClass__Ljava_lang_Object_2I)
```

Please suggest any solution for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the permissions of every directory in the file's path? What are the permissions on the file itself, and is the file *executable*?

Answer (score 0):

I recently stumbled in the same problem. Enabling `android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false` to your `gradle.properties` may solve the problem.

Answer found here: https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-android/issues/576#issuecomment-494148605

Comment: is this answer still relevant for android Gradle plugin 3.6.+? I see that it's added to the doc for version 3.3.+